# Efficiently aggregate a resampled collection of datetimes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Given the following dataset as a pandas dataframe df:

```
index(as DateTime object) |  Name        |  Amount    |  IncomeOutcome
---------------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-28                |  Customer1   |  200.0     |  Income
2019-01-31                |  Customer1   |  200.0     |  Income
2019-01-31                |  Customer2   |  100.0     |  Income
2019-01-28                |  Customer2   |  -100.0    |  Outcome
2019-01-31                |  Customer2   |  -100.0    |  Outcome
```

We perform the following steps:

```
grouped = df.groupby("Name", "IncomeOutcome")
sampled_by_month = grouped.resample("M")
aggregated = sampled_by_month.agg({"MonthlyCount": "size", "Amount": "sum"})
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
Name       |  IncomeOutcome   |  Amount    |  MonthlyCount
------------------------------------------------------------
Customer1  |  Income          |  400.0     |  2
Customer2  |  Income          |  100.0     |  1
Customer2  |  Outcome         |  -200.0    |  2
```

The last step performs very poorly, possibly related to [Pandas Issue #20660](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20660)
My first intention was to convert all datetime objects to int64, which leaves me with the question on how to resample the converted data by month.

Any suggestions on that issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Ben, what is the final form of data you're looking to get? Can you make a small dataframe example of your desired ouput? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Ollie, I updated the description. I hope this makes it more clear what I am trying to achieve.

The sampled_by_month variable should hold groups with a an array of datetime objects as the value, which seems to be very slow.

Comment: Fixed a possible bug in your input. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, seems to be correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps we can optimise your solution by having the resampling done only on a single column ("Amount", the column of interest).

```
(df.groupby(["Name", "IncomeOutcome"])['Amount']
   .resample("M")
   .agg(['sum','size'])
   .rename({'sum':'Amount', 'size': 'MonthlyCount'}, axis=1)
   .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index())

        Name IncomeOutcome  Amount  MonthlyCount
0  Customer1        Income   400.0             2
1  Customer2        Income   100.0             1
2  Customer2       Outcome  -200.0             2
```

If this is still too slow, then I think the problem could be that the `resample` being *within* the `groupby` slows things down. Perhaps you can try grouping by all 3 predicates with a single `groupby` call. For the date resampling, try `pd.Grouper`.

```
(df.groupby(['Name', 'IncomeOutcome', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['Amount']
   .agg([ ('Amount', 'sum'), ('MonthlyCount', 'size')])
   .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index())

        Name IncomeOutcome  Amount  MonthlyCount
0  Customer1        Income   400.0             2
1  Customer2        Income   100.0             1
2  Customer2       Outcome  -200.0             2
```

Performance wise, this should come out faster.

---

**Performance**

Let's try setting up a more general DataFrame for the purpose of testing.

```
# Setup
df_ = df.copy()
df1 = pd.concat([df_.reset_index()] * 100, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([
        df1.replace({'Customer1': f'Customer{i}', 'Customer2': f'Customer{i+1}'}) 
        for i in range(1, 98, 2)], ignore_index=True) 
df = df.set_index('index')

df.shape
# (24500, 3)
```

```
%%timeit 
(df.groupby(["Name", "IncomeOutcome"])['Amount']
   .resample("M")
   .agg(['sum','size'])
   .rename({'sum':'Amount', 'size': 'MonthlyCount'}, axis=1)
   .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index())

%%timeit
(df.groupby(['Name', 'IncomeOutcome', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['Amount']
   .agg([ ('Amount', 'sum'), ('MonthlyCount', 'size')])
   .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index())

1.71 s ± 85.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
24.2 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I test it 2 days ago with geenral data and get different output for your second code

Comment: @jezrael ah yes I think there was a bug in their question. [I fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54477866/3) and pinged them asking them to check if it was correct.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for your answer! I will examine it tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: @Ben Let me know if there's anything. Thanks.

Comment: A point to clarify future readers:The second method, using the pd.Grouper, which is way faster than the first one, produces a Dataframe WITHOUT NaN rows. Example: If you are resampling for daily data, missing days WILL NOT APPEAR as NaN rows. Only the traditional "resampling()" will produce rows with missing days, weeks, etc. I believe that is why the total number of rows differs from theses approaches.